# Sonar - how to create sub projects with sonnar-runner

Tags: configuration, static-analysis, sonarqube

I have a Java project which consists of a couple of modules. I am using Sonar to statically analyse my code. Currently I am using sonar-runner to analyse each of the modules, and they appear as different Projects in the main page of Sonar. I would like to see the main project name on the main page, and, once I will click on it, and than on "Components"  - to see all of it's modules as sub-projects - just like it appears here:

http://nemo.sonarsource.org/components/index/308832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible with Java runner. Only Maven plugin and Ant task support project structures with modules.

Note that the modules of C# projects are automatically created from the VisualStudio solution file, even if the Java runner is used.

Answer (score 1):

Do you project use Maven ?If it is the case it should work fine if you have a pom.xml for each module and one for your parent module.