# Sonarqube - subprojects from Visual Studio solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have 2 projects configured in a jenkins server that launch each a sonarqube analysis.
The configuration for both projects is the same and looks like that:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=company:%PROJ_NAME%
sonar.projectName=%PROJ_NAME%
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=/src/.
sonar.language=cs
sonar.fxcop.mode=skip
sonar.gendarme.mode=skip
sonar.ndeps.mode=skip
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.exclusions=**/*Designer.cs

# ----- Unit Test Results
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=%TEST_DIRECTORY%TestResults.trx

# ----- Code Coverage
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=%TEST_DIRECTORY%CodeCoverage.coveragexml
```

The problem is, I've got one project where all the visual studio projects have their own subproject in sonar, and the other don't.

I've read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537642/4606752) that it is the standard behaviour, and I'm searching why the other project doesn't behave the same.

Are there any reason why the subprojects are not created ?

Sonar runner is v2.4.1 and sonar is v5.2.1